# Run flask file on wlan1 instead of wlan0

Tags: python, flask

I have a raspberry pi, a flask server, a flask client, and two different networks.

when I connect a wifi adapter to the raspberry pi I can see that I have a new interface called "wlan1" is there a way to run a the server for example on "wlan0" and the client on "wlan1".

what I'm trying to do is run the server on a different network than the client (while both of them are on the pi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Server:**

For the server part, you need to "bind" the listening socket to the IP address of wlan0.

1. Find the IP address of wlan0 using `ifconfig wlan0` or `ip addr show dev wlan0` (e.g. 192.168.0.2)
2. Bind the Flask server to that IP address using `app.run(host='192.168.0.2', port=80)`

If you bind to 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable from all network devices.

**Client**:

A little bit more involved, take a look at how "routing tables" work for the theory.

1. Find out the IP address of the *server* that your client will connect to (e.g. 93.184.216.34)
2. Find out the IP address of the default gateway on the interface wlan1, for example with `ip route` (look for "default via  dev wlan1"), e.g. "default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan1"
3. Add a route to that IP address via the gateway and interface, using `route add 93.184.216.34 gw 192.168.1.1 dev wlan1`

Note that the routing table will affect all programs on the raspberry pi, not just your client application.